# Empty GET data with onclick="$.get()"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, tablesorter

I got a script which I use my table sorter script to store the sort order when the page gets refreshed. It used to work perfectly however it's suddenly stopped working and I have no idea. It's creating the session variables however they are empty.

```
'ClaimSort' => string '' (length=0)
  'ClaimSort2' => string '' (length=0)
```

The link is working but it would appear that I am not passing the _GET data no longer. Can anyone help...

When clicking on a `<th>` within the table I initiate the following:

```
onclick='$.get("ajax/storeSort.php", {ClaimSort:0}, function(data){});'
```

within storeSort.php I have the following:

```
if ( $_SESSION["ClaimSort"] == $_GET['ClaimSort'] && $_SESSION["ClaimSort2"] == '0' ) {
    $_SESSION["ClaimSort"] = $_GET['ClaimSort'];
    $_SESSION["ClaimSort2"] = '1';
}elseif ( $_SESSION["ClaimSort"] == $_GET['ClaimSort'] && $_SESSION["ClaimSort2"] == '1' ) {
    $_SESSION["ClaimSort"] = $_GET['ClaimSort'];
    $_SESSION["ClaimSort2"] = '0';
}else{
    $_SESSION["ClaimSort"] = $_GET['ClaimSort'];
    $_SESSION["ClaimSort2"] = '0';
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION["ClaimSort2"]` is only set by your php code and is either 1 or 0 or 0. If it's empty, it's not this part of your code which causes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was no issue with the code, turns out there was a php error which was preventing it from executing fully and I was only able to pick this up from the Apache logs on the server.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment at your question!? Thx for the up vote, glad to help you out. ;)